# Making 2 Android ListViews on same screen be the same height

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, android-linearlayout

I have an activity where the main area of the screen is 2 list views.  One above the Other.
Clicking on an item in the Top list view changes what's displayed in the lower listview.

The problem is that I can't seem to force each list to always use 1/2 of the available space.  If the top list has 100 items, and the bottom has 1 - the bottom list completely disappears and the top list takes up all the space.

I've read several similar questions here - and they all seem to say just wrap the ListView's in their own LinearLayouts and it works.  Not for me.  The bottom list still collapsed to either small or gone if it only has a few items in it.

This is my xml:

```
  DELETED old XML due to posting size limit.
```

So, I tried the first suggestion - which doesn't work.  The lists are only the same size if the number of items in the lists is roughly similar.  If one list has 100 items, and the other has 3, the 3 item list takes much less screen space.  ALSO if the both lists are relatively short, they don't even fill the screen, and leave a blank white area at the bottom.  Note that there ARE other required controls in this screen, some of which are made visible/gone as needed.

Here is the updated XML:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
                android:id="@+id/prevButton"
                style="@style/prevButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:onClick="onPrevResult" />

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUTextView
                android:id="@+id/meet_name"
                style="@style/sans.white.16.bold"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:text="@string/example_meet_name_long" />

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
                android:id="@+id/nextButton"
                style="@style/nextButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:onClick="onNextResult" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <RadioGroup
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="6dp" >

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TURadioButton
                android:id="@+id/filter_mine"
                style="@style/sans.white.14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_segment_left"
                android:button="@drawable/small_crap"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onFilterMine"
                android:text="@string/my_kids" />

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TURadioButton
                android:id="@+id/filter_team"
                style="@style/sans.white.14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_segment_mid"
                android:button="@drawable/small_crap"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onFilterTeam"
                android:text="@string/my_team" />

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TURadioButton
                android:id="@+id/filter_all"
                style="@style/sans.white.14"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:background="@drawable/grey_segment_right"
                android:button="@drawable/small_crap"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onFilterAll"
                android:text="@string/all" />
        </RadioGroup>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
                android:id="@+id/search_button"
                style="@style/searchButton"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="onSearch" />

            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_weight="1.0"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TURadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/filter_events"
                    style="@style/sans.white.14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="@drawable/grey_segment_left"
                    android:button="@drawable/small_crap"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="onFilterEvents"
                    android:text="@string/events" />

                <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TURadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/filter_swimmers"
                    style="@style/sans.white.14"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="0"
                    android:background="@drawable/grey_segment_right"
                    android:button="@drawable/small_crap"
                    android:checked="true"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:onClick="onFilterSwimmers"
                    android:text="@string/swimmers" />
            </RadioGroup>

            <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
                android:id="@+id/help_button"
                style="@style/helpButton"
                android:layout_margin="4dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:onClick="showHelp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout> <!-- end of heading -->

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tophdr_event"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_filter_gender"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onFilterGender"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/gender" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_filter_distance"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onFilterDistance"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/distance" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_filter_stroke"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onFilterStroke"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="@string/stroke" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_filter_age"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onFilterAge"
            android:paddingLeft="26dp"
            android:text="@string/age" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/tophdr_swimmer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUTextView
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/swimmer" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUTextView
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/event_age" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUTextView
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/team" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/meet_result_top_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FF333333" />

    <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUTextView
        android:id="@+id/meet_result_top_empty"
        style="@style/sans.white.18.bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FF333333"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/no_matching_data"
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bothdr_event"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_event"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortEvent"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/event" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_evpos"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortPos"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/position" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_evpoints"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortPointsE"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/points" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_evtime"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortTimeE"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:text="@string/time" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bothdr_swimmer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="0"
        android:background="#FF000000"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_swimmer"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortSwimmer"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="@string/swimmer" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_team"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortTeam"
            android:paddingLeft="14dp"
            android:text="@string/team" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_swpos"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortEvent"
            android:paddingLeft="25dp"
            android:text="@string/position" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_swpoints"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortPointsS"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:text="@string/points" />

        <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_sort_swtime"
            style="@style/sans.white.12"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#FF000000"
            android:drawableRight="@drawable/filter"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:onClick="onSortTimeS"
            android:paddingLeft="4dp"
            android:text="@string/time" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/meet_result_bot_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FF333333"
        android:visibility="visible" >
    </ListView>

    <com.teamunify.ondeck.widget.TUTextView
        android:id="@+id/meet_result_bot_empty"
        style="@style/sans.white.18.bold"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:background="#FF333333"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/meet_manage:no_entries"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

It should have a form like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: See my updated XML above.
Also note that most of the other times this has been asked, that exact form for the XML has failed.